# Gatsby: Looping when shadowing components by Extending

Tags: gatsby, shadowing

The docs for the theme-api https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/theme-api/ describe Extending, where a key idea is that your extending code includes an

import XXX from "gatsby-theme-amazying/src/components/header".

When I first came across this, I used as an import target the name of the file I was extending -- including the trailing file type - .../header.js in this example.

When I did that, the gatsby develop ran, but the browser went into a loop.
When I did that, the gatsby build step in generating the static html went into a loop.

Either this is a bug, or the docs should be updated to indicate that the import in your "extending" code *must not* include the file type.

Comment: Did you consider filing an issue here https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues ?

Comment: I will if someone can corroborate this, just so I know it's not just some mistake on my part.

Comment: I can. Do you have a repository so I can replicate your issue?

Comment: I opened an issue with gatsby, here https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/16383.

It includes very easy instructions for reproducing this.